# idea javaFx: Подскажите как менять элемент SceneBuilder (Sample.fxml) из Controller.java

Tags: javafx

Собственно суть:
Есть графический интерфейс написанный "мастером"(который SceneBuilder) через графическую обложку javaFX 2.0 (sample.fxml)
к нему опять-же мастером сформирован Controller.java

Задача используя методы объектов менять сами объекты.
например заполнить содержимое "combobox" новыми значениями.

Однако, поскольку все создавал "SceneBuilder" , не очень понятно как обращаться к уже существующим объектам.

Прошу подсказать как это делать.

Comment: пропишите необходимым объектам fx:id через SceneBuilder и создайте поле аналогичного типа в контроллере, где имя поля такое же как и fx:id. Перед полем добавьте аннотация @FXML. Таким образом вы получите доступ к объекту внутри контроллера.

Comment: и это правильный ответ!

Comment: @АлександрСавостьянов, ответы — в ответы, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

спасибо, 
прописал внутри класса "Controller" так

> ```
> @FXML
> public ComboBox<String> BoxLogins;
> ```
>
> после этого работает, 
>   т.е. становится доступным.